# My trained model return the same predict for all input images

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm very new to this. I just trained a model following instruction from kaggle and another website. The trained model works fine with train images but whenever i try to input a new image to predict, the result is always the same.
The accuracy is 0.9975000023841858
`

```
X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)

X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)
X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=3)
```

`Here is the model`

```
weight_decay = 1e-4

num_classes = 12

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=(128,128,1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
 
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="linear"))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=5, 
                    validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
                    verbose = 1,
                    initial_epoch=0)
```

`

When i tried to test the train image

`

```
predicted_classes = model.predict(X_train[:,:,:,:])
predicted_classes = np.argmax(np.round(predicted_classes), axis=1)

k = X_train.shape[0] #18000
r = np.random.randint(k) #random in 18000
print("Prediction:", predicted_classes[4])
```

Prediction: 8`

My input image

`

```
imgTest = tf.keras.utils.load_img('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/finger.jpg')
imgTest = np.array(imgTest)
imgTest = cv2.cvtColor(imgTest, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgTest = cv2.resize(imgTest, (128, 128))
imgTest = np.expand_dims(imgTest, axis=0)
# imgTest = imgTest.reshape((1, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1))
# imgTest = imgTest/255
print(imgTest.shape)
predicted_classes_test = model.predict(imgTest)
predicted_classes_test = np.argmax(np.round(predicted_classes_test), axis=1)
print("Prediction:", predicted_classes_test)
```

Prediction: [7]`

I tried changing the shape of the input image so that it's the same as the train images but doesn't work
I looked for people having the same mistake to see if i can find any solutions but nothing works
Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the model? Why is it return the same value for all the images that i input?

Comment: There can be a number of reasons. First of all the  final accuracy itself is not enough to reason about model being valid or not. You need to see train vs test accuracy graph (and other metrics as well, like recall, precision, F1 score - all depends on a model and usecase ) to see if the model is not overfitted (that means it "learned" the train data and is not predicting at all).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me how do i do that? I test the model on train image, it still works correctly